# Postgresql comment on specific role

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to store a specific user's description in the Postgres by doing this:

```
comment on role blog is 'blog user long name';
```

However, when I look for it in the pg_description table it is not there:

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_description where description like '%blog%';
```

Returns no results. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

The role comments are stored in the "pg_catalog.pg_shdescription" table.

Comment: [The catalog pg_shdescription stores optional descriptions (comments) for shared database objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/catalog-pg-shdescription.html)

Comment: You could maybe add this comment to your answer and even quote a couple of relevant passages from the link?